# html table cell with fixed size compressed in div

Tags: html, css

The css file is as follows:

```
   #table_container {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: scroll;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    table, tr,td{
       border: 2px solid blue;
       border-collapse: collapse;
    } 

    td {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
    }
```

You can refer to the following link:
https://jsfiddle.net/xuvtge5n/

I set the table cell to a fixed size 30px * 30px

However, when the dimension of table increase to a large size, like 60*60, the cell will be compressed together and become a rectangle. The length displayed should be 30px but the width is not.

I set the overflow property to scroll or auto but it does not help.

I want the table can be scrolled inside the div vertically and horizontally and display the table cell like a square without compressing together.

Please tell if anything missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set table width 100% and [layout as `fixed`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xuvtge5n/2/

Comment: Your example solve the problem when the dimension is large, but when the table dimension become 3*3 instead of 60* 60 in my example, the display of table cell is a rectangle instead. Any ways to make it displays as a square with different dimension of the table ?

Comment: Then calculate width of the table as 60×<cell count> and set it to the table via js